# Value doesn't work when I try to display the name

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using a selectbox to select a name from a list.

I am trying to put a source value in the selectbox using the value but nothing is appearing to me. Does anyone know how I can submit a root name without having to make a selection?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyezvl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let datas of array">
    <dx-select-box [value]="datas.name"> </dx-select-box>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the incorrect syntax for DevExtreme select box. You need to pass the value to `valueExpr` and the display value to `displayExpr` like below. There is no need for `ngFor` with `dx-select-box`. Instead, you just need to pass the array to `items`.

```html
<dx-select-box [items]="array" valueExpr="id" displayExpr="name"></dx-select-box>
```

Comment: **Note**: On StackBlitz, after pasting the above code in the html, refresh the in-built browser on the right. The StackBlitz auto-refresh does not seem to make it work properly.

Comment: displayExpr and valueExpr are for the options in the dx-select-box.
Is there a way to set the value of the select-box too, in Angular 8?